# Unable to link an executable to shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a `cmake` project where I am trying to link the executable to the shared library. But it is not getting linked. After searching enough and not finding any useful solutions, I'm posting my question here, please let me know if there are any obvious mistakes as I am not familiar with `cmake`

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
# Set Project Name
set(PROJECT_NAME myproj)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
# Tell Cmake to invoke gcc with specific flags. Use c++11 standard.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Include all headers 
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../public/include)

# Driver Program
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
)
# Dont know what to do about this
#set( CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH true)

link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../relative/path/to/sharedlib) #contains libshared.so

# Generate Executable, trying to generate shared library to see if it generates # correct dependencies
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Link the libraries

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../relative/path/to/sharedlib/libshared.so)
```

Here is the steps I have tried and some observations.

1. If I generate a shared library instead of an executable, it is able to find the dependent shared library(i.e libshared.so)

   `ldd myproj.so`

   `libshared.so => full/path/to/sharedlib/libshared.so (0x00007fa26c263000)`

I did not fully understand what it meant, but it is able to find the shared library is what I guessed.

2. If I try to generate an executable instead of shared library, I see undefined reference errors to the functions within the library.
3. I tried just `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} shared)` as well and it gave same error.

Any clues as to how can I get the shared library linked to my executable? Thanks

Comment: I don't know cmake, so I can't really answer, but I think it wouldn't hurt to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Beta, I understand that, but I cant share the library (libshared.so which I am referring to). I would be sued for that.

Comment: Have you tried building your own shared library?

Comment: I dont have the source code and build scripts for building the shared library. I have to make use of that library in my project.

Comment: [rubs temples] The problem does not appear to be *within* the shared library; the problem appears to be *linking* your code to the shared library. So it would be useful to know whether you can link code to a simple shared library of your own making, even if that shared library doesn't do very much.

Comment: You don't need to specify path to the shared library in `target_link_libraries` if you already set it in `link_directories` (also make sure you have that directive before `add_executable`). I suppose this should be enough: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} shared)`. And are you sure that the library contains symbols you want to use?

Comment: Try using ``make VERBOSE=1`` to see exactly what the link step is doing. The post the errors if you still need help.